# Actionscript, accessing JSON objects dymically

Tags: json, flash, syntax, actionscript

I am using JSON.parse(event.target.data) to load JSON data into an object.

I then access this object like this

```
jsonObj.product_1.title
```

Is it possible to dynamically set "product_1" so I can iterate through a loop for each product.

I am able to do this if each tree of the object has no name, as they can be accessed using [0], but once they have a name I seem to have to use the name.

I am trying to get to

```
jsonObj.[0].title
jsonObj.[1].title
jsonObj.[2].title
```

or

```
jsonObj.["product_1"].title
jsonObj.["product_2"].title
jsonObj.["product_3"].title
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your `jsonObj.["product_1"].title` is **very close**, just remove the `.` before the `[`:

```
jsonObj["product_1"].title
```

Note that the string you're using there can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup.

In JavaScript and ActionScript, you can access an object property with dot notation and a *literal* property name (`obj.foo`), or with brackets notation and a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`).*

So for instance:

```
var n:Number = 0;
while (jsonObj["product_" + n]) {
    // Do something with `jsonObj["product_" + n].title`
    ++n;
}
```

---

* JavaScript also now has `Symbol` property names which you also use brackets with, but that's not germane here.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `Associative Array` (Dictionary/Map) and you can iterator the array's items via `for in` and `for each in` statements.

#### Define Associative Array:

```
var foodBasket:Object = {apple:"Red", orange:"Orange", corn:"Yellow"};
```

#### `for in` iterate-based on the key:

```
for (var veggie:Object in foodBasket) {
   trace(veggie, foodBasket[veggie] );
}
```

#### key iterate output:

```
[trace] corn Yellow
[trace] apple Red
[trace] orange Orange
```

#### `for each in` iterate-based on value, not key:

```
for each (var color:Object in foodBasket)
{
   trace(color);
}
```

#### value iterate output:

```
[trace] Yellow
[trace] Red
[trace] Orange
```